# Should "tablet" be capitalized in a school essay?

Tags: capitalization, technology

Should "tablet" be capitalized? Such as: "The last ten years has brought us smartphones, tablets, 3-D visual entertainment..." etc.

Comment: You should also say "The last ten years have...."  The topic is plural, so you don't use an s-type verb.  Rule of thumb: one s-type , if you get my drift.

Comment: Or for crispness perhaps "The last decade has ..."

Answer (score 11):

No.  None of these are trademarked terms.  A tablet PC is a type of computer.  It's not a brand or model name.  It should only be capitalized under special circumstances, like if it's in the title, included in a model name, or at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: *The Tablet* is also a newspaper, so *Tablets* might in theory refer to several of them (maybe a bundle of copies).

Comment: So should PC be capitalised, presumably you aren't referring to the  original IBM(tm) PC(tm) ?

Comment: Yes because it's an acronym for personal computer, which you don't need to capitalize.  So, PC is capitalized.